# How to ensure private gems are up to date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

We have a number of private (common) gems which we include in all of our ruby projects.  We include them from GitHub, and use release tags to specify a version.

`gem 'aswesome_gem', :git => 'git@github.com:evantahler/aswesome_gem.git', :tag => 'v2.0.28'`

However, we have been rapidly iterating on our gems, and it is becoming a pain to keep all of our projects up to date.  I would prefer not to host our own gem server (Gem in a Box, etc).  The reason we use tags and not branches (`:branch => 'production'`) is that bundler will not update the branch if it exists.

Is there an extension to bundler that would let me specify that every time `bundle install` is run, bundler would forcibly update the local cached copy to the branch in question (even though it might already be checked out)?  I think that I essentially want to `git pull` on every git-based gem (which happens to be specified by a `:branch`)  Bundler's default behavior assumes a gem is up to date if the branch exists (regardless of parity with origin).

Help?

Comment: Oh, and to clarify: These gems are meant to always be up-to-date in all projects. Image that they are common Capistrano tools for deployment or config files

Comment: Be aware that this it totally orthogonal to what Bundler is trying to achieve, which is a *consistent, unchanging* gem environment

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do `bundle update` to get the latest versions of your gems.

Comment: You can also do `bundle update gemname` to update just a single gem.

Comment: Ahh! Perhaps we'll try writing an extension to bundler that will `bundle update gem_a gem_b` before `bundle install`.  Good tip!